# Inner select on one to many

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 2 tables event + event_artist

### event

```
eventId | eventName  
-------------------
1 , gig1  
2, gig2
```

### event_artist

```
eventId, artistName 
------------------- 
1, Led Zip  
1, The Beatles
```

ie Led Zep and the Beatles are both playing @ Gig1

I need to create the SQl to bind to a gridview ( you necessarily need to know about gridviews to answers this )

The results that i want would look like this
eventId = 1, EventName = Gig1. ArtistLineup = Led Zep, The beatles

So i need to create an alias ArtistLineup that would list all the artist. Via an inner select i think.

Any thoughts on what this would look like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saw this in SQL Server Magazine- not great, and the total list will have an upper length limit, but:

```
drop table event
go

drop table event_artist
go

create table event (eventid int, eventname varchar(255))
go

create table event_artist (eventid int, artistname varchar(255))
go

insert into event values (1, 'gig1')
go

insert into event values (2, 'gig2')
go

insert into event_artist values (1, 'Led Zip')
go

insert into event_artist values (1, 'The Beatles')
go

drop function Event_Display
go

create function Event_Display (@EventID int) returns varchar(2000) as
begin
    declare @artistList varchar(2000)
    set @artistList=''

    select @artistList=@artistList + ', ' + isnull(artistname,'') 
    from event_artist 
    where eventid=@EventID

    return substring(@artistList,3,2000)  --eliminate initial comma
end
go

select event.eventid, event.eventname, dbo.Event_Display(event.eventid) from event
```

```
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
1           gig1        Led Zip, The Beatles

2           gig2
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't have anything built in to concatenate values in one statement like that.  You could build the strings, but it has to be done one at a time.

However, you can get around this by building your own [custom aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43940/custom-aggregate-functions-in-ms-sql-server) (requires messy games with ActiveX objects in SQL Server 2000)

Answer (score 0):

you might want to try something like this:
[Why does this SQL script work as it does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279444/why-does-this-sql-script-work-as-it-does)

Answer (score 0):

ScottK's answer is basically the one you want.  Here's the rest of mine:

The query:

```
select e.*, dbo.ArtistList(e.EventId) as ArtistList
from [event] e
```

The function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ArtistList<br>
(
    -- Add the parameters for the function here<br>
    @EventId int<br>
)
RETURNS varchar(MAX)<br>
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @ArtistList varchar(MAX)
    -- Add the T-SQL statements to compute the return value here
    SELECT @ArtistList = COALESCE(@ArtistList + ', ', '') + Artist
    FROM EventArtist
    WHERE EventId = @EventId
    -- Return the result of the function
    RETURN @ArtistList
END
GO
```

The only difference between my answer and ScottK's you might take note of is my use of `varchar(MAX)`. That should pretty much address any concerns about the list of artists being truncated.

I've deleted my previous (incomplete) answer.

Comment: That only works for one item at a time.  He'd have to run those in a cursor if he wants more than one result, which is less than desirable.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  My revised answer addresses the issue you raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use the clever FOR XML trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-mssql) posted by [Kevin Fairchild](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3743/kevin-fairchild) (I've modified it to take account of band names which will include spaces):

```
/*
create table [event] (eventid int, eventname varchar(255))
create table event_artist (eventid int, artistname varchar(255))
insert into [event] values (1, 'gig1')
insert into [event] values (2, 'gig2')
insert into event_artist values (1, 'Led Zip')
insert into event_artist values (1, 'The Beatles')
*/

SELECT  e.eventid
       ,e.eventname
       ,REPLACE(REPLACE(RTRIM((
                               SELECT   artistname + '| '
                               FROM     [event_artist]
                               WHERE    eventid = e.eventid
                              FOR
                               XML PATH('')
                              )), '| ', ', '), '|', '') AS artists
FROM    [event] AS e
```

Note that this requires columns in the FOR XML to be unnamed (named columns get an XML wrapper).